# Change custom taxonomy in woocommerce programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the value of a custom taxonomy in woocommerce.

```
function get_pw_by_email($email) {

  $products = get_posts(array('post_type' =>'product', 'tax_query' =>array(array('taxonomy' =>'pa_e-mail', 'field' =>'name', 'terms' =>$email))));

  $terms = wp_get_post_terms($products[0] ->ID, 'pa_pw', true);
  
  if (empty($terms)) {
    return '';
  }

  return $terms[0]->name;
}
```

Like this I can get the correct taxonomy value. But now I want to create a random number and update that value - without loosing all other other taxonomies of that product.

Update: I was able to solve it.

```
function get_pw_by_email($email) {
    
  $products = get_posts(array('post_type' =>'product', 'tax_query' =>array(array('taxonomy' =>'pa_e-mail', 'field' =>'name', 'terms' =>$email))));
    
  if (empty($products)) {
    return '';
  }
  
    $random_number = rand(10000000, 99999999);

    $attributes = get_post_meta($products[0] ->ID, '_product_attributes', true);

    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($products[0]->ID, 'pa_pw', true);

    if (isset($terms[0]->name)) {
      // pa_pw attribute is already set for the product, set its value
      wp_set_post_terms($products[0] ->ID, $random_number, 'pa_pw', false);
    } else {
      // pa_pw attribute is not set for the product, add it and set its value
      $attributes['pa_pw'] = array('name' => 'pa_pw','value' => null,'is_visible' => '0','is_taxonomy' => '1',);
      update_post_meta($products[0] ->ID, '_product_attributes', $attributes);
      wp_set_post_terms($products[0] ->ID, $random_number, 'pa_pw', false);
    }

    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($products[0]->ID, 'pa_pw', true);
    
  if (empty($terms)) {
    return '';
  }
  
  
  return $terms[0]->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this on a per-product basis, and not modifying the global taxonomies, one option could be getting the term you want to replace (as you're doing now), remove it with [wp_remove_object_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remove_object_terms/), then use [wp_set_post_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_terms/) to append the new, modified term.

Comment: Ah, yes thank for pointing that out to first remove and then to append. Will try!